# How to fix accessoryButton on tableview cell programatically using autolayouts

Tags: ios, swift

Hi i am beginner in iOS and i am trying add `accessoryButton` on `tableViewCell` using auto-layouts `constraintsWithVisualFormat` but it is not adding please help me some one

```
    accessorybutton = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"cellbutton.png"]];
    accessorybutton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    [accessorybutton setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];
    [accessorybutton sizeToFit];
    [Cell.contentView addSubview:accessorybutton];

    NSDictionary * views = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(accessoryView);

    NSArray * horizentalConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-[accessorybutton]-20-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:views];

    NSArray * verticalConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-5-[accessorybutton]-5-|"options:0 metrics:nil views:views];
```

but `accessoryView` is not adding on `UITableViewCell`, what did i do here wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to set auto layout for `accessoryView`.

you can set `accessoryView` like below syntax.

```
cell.accessoryView = accessorybutton;
```